# Query in current document and sub document mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections Orders and Books , I want to query on Order (code) and Book ( name, number) same time with a string value, to check if any of these three value matches with string and return those Orders documents

```
Orders :{   
_id: 6456353b9bdc3f78e546e557,  
code: '12344,   
bookId: 645635649bdc3f78e546e560  
}
```

```
Books :{   
_id :645635649bdc3f78e546e560,    
name: "golden",  
number: "12321"   
}
```

Response I want

```
{
_id: 6456353b9bdc3f78e546e557,    
code: '12344',    
bookId: {   
   _id :645635649bdc3f78e546e560,   
   name: "golden",   
   number: "12321"   
  }  
}
```

I have tried this query but it is not returning result for order (code)

```
Order.aggregate([     
        {         
          $lookup: {       
            from: 'books',               
            localField: 'bookId',                 
            foreignField: '_id',                
            pipeline: [{                        
               $match: {          
                  $or: [                 
                    { code: { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i') } },         
                    { name: { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i') } },            
                    { number: { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i') } },          
                  ],         
                },        
              },        
            ],          
            as: 'bookId',       
          },       
        },           
        { $unwind: '$bookId' },     
      }  

])
```

Comment: What is `search` in your code? Could you use the `localField`/`foreignField` syntax for `$lookup`? If not probably need to use `let` to see the value that you want to search on

Comment: search is string value,

Comment: Have you tried using { $match: { $expr: { $or: .... like in mongodb docs? See the example at the end https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-single-equality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
    Orders.aggregate([     
        {         
          $lookup: {       
            from: 'books',               
            localField: 'bookId',                 
            foreignField: '_id',                         
            as: 'bookId',       
          },       
        },           
        { $unwind: '$bookId' },     
        {            
          $match: {          
                  $or: [                 
                    { code: { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i') } },         
                    { 'bookId.name': { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i') } },            
                    { 'bookId.number': { $regex: new RegExp(search, 'i') } },          
                  ],         
                },        
          }
      }
])
```